# using B tree index with like operator

Tags: database, oracle, indexing, b-tree

I have a question about using index in Oracle.
Suppose table has *B tree* index created on column columnA, which has high cardinality or unique.
This table has 1KK rows.
I make a query example `where columnA like 'A%'` 
Suppose in this example this query will return me 90 percent of data.  
 
So some questions:

1. Will oracle determine to use index or not?
2. If oracle will determine itself, what is the percentage value (example 50%) when oracle will use index. Example 30% use index, 40% will not use? And when I would benefit from using indexes.
3. Can I force oracle to use index or not depending on query myself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) No. 2) Approximately 10%. 3) Sometimes (hints)

Comment: 1) Maybe: "The LIKE comparison may invoke an index as long as the wildcard character is not in the leading position—in other words, the expression LIKE ‘%SMITH’ will not invoke an index, but LIKE ‘SMITH%’ may invoke an index"

Comment: If the query is returning 90% of the data then there's no need for an index and Oracle won't use one @Multisync. Your comment about the position of wildcards applies if the column has a significantly higher cardinality only.